# What kind of program was Sark?

Tags: tron

In the movie Tron (1982) we get to know most of the programs' functions, original or actual.

So, for example, we're told that Tron is a security program, Ram an actuarial program, Dumont an Input/Output program, even it is stated that the Master Control Program was originally a chess game.

But what kind of program was [Sark](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Sark), the "brutal and needlessly sadistic" commander of the MCP, played by David Warner?

Comment: Ham generator!!  Or actually, probably a security program very similar to Tron, just created by Dillinger to assist the MCPs efforts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sark appears to be a custom program, designed specifically to assist and support the MCP on the grid. It's persistently referred to, in the film's [official novelisation](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON_(novelization)) as "the Command Program".

> That moment seemed near. The User-Believer shifted uneasily as he
>   waited. He was determined to do his best; that was as it should be
>   with a program. But **his adversary was Sark, the Command Program.**
>
> Sark the Red, the unbeaten; Sark the tall, merciless Warrior, had won
>   so consistently that he no longer kept track of his victories. It was
>   Sark who served as Lord of the System, under the rulership of the
>   Master Control Program. **Sark’s mission, the Master Control Program’s
>   prime objective, was to wipe out all loyalty to the Users.**